# Another method for selecting an underneath object(s)

Tags: inkscape, selections

One method to select an underneath object (and other objects deeper in Z-order) is clicking it (repeatedly) with while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down.

Is there another method, maybe with some advantage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and *rotate the mouse wheel*.

The advantage of this method lies in temporary displaying

- the currently selected object in *full opacity,* while
- all other objects in the stack as *semitransparent*.

  [image]

Comment: That does not seem to work. I think you mean you should open the "Layers & Objects" dialog first.

Comment: @s.ouchene, no dialog is necessary. It works just out of the box.

Comment: I have tested that on both Inkscape 1.3-dev and Inkscape 1.2 and it doesn't work unless you use the Layers & Objects dialog.

Comment: @s.ouchene, I don't know how to help you, for me, it works both in Inkscape 1.1 and 1.2, without opening any dialog. I wish you to solve it somehow.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post, my bad. on the L&O dialog it highlights objects (not necessarily overlapping) but in your answer, the trick works only with overlapping objects.

Comment: @s.ouchene, I'm glad that it works for you, too.:-)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend learning to make selections in the objects panel as an alternative. It can happen that something has been sunken below opaque bigger shapes - you cannot Alt+Click it because its place is not sure. But it can be selected by clicking in the objects panel. There you can access also items inside groups.

In complex works it's useful to rename at least some items and groups in the objects panel. Renaming layers is even more useful if there's several of them.

In objects panel one can lock and also hide items which shouldn't be got selected accidentally.